# How to get Object[] from Mono<Object[]> and how to filter Flux<Object>

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I'm creating a REST API that is supposed to fetch repositories that are not forks and, for each repository, a list of branches. However, I have a problem because:

1. I don't know how to filter the response in the web client to check if a repository is a fork.
   Should I assign webClient response to a variable and then filter?
2. I don't know how to extract Branch[] from Mono<Branch[]> in order to create a ResponseRepo.

I've done this with RestTemplate, but I'd like to do it with WebClient in a non-blocking way.

Repo record
`public record Repo(String name, Owner owner, Boolean fork) {}`

Branch record
`public record Branch(String name, Commit commit) {}`

ResponseRepo record
`public record ResponseRepo(String name, String ownerLogin, Branch[] branches) {}`

```
@Service
public class RepoServiceImpl implements RepoService {

    private final WebClient webClient;

    public RepoServiceImpl(WebClient.Builder builder) {
        this.webClient = builder.baseUrl("https://api.github.com").build();
    }

    public Flux<ResponseRepo> getReposInfo(String username) {
        return getRepos(username)
                .flatMap(repo -> {
                    String name = repo.name();
                        String ownerLogin = repo.owner().login();
                        Mono<Branch[]> branches = getBranches(username, repo.name());
                        return new ResponseRepo(name, ownerLogin, branches);
                })
    }

    private Flux<Repo> getRepos(String username) {
        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/users/" + username + "/repos")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToFlux(Repo.class);
    }

    private Mono<Branch[]> getBranches(String username, String repo) {
        return webClient
                .get()
                .uri("/repos/" + username + "/" + repo + "/branches")
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(Branch[].class);
    }
}
```

Here, I want to get Branch[] from Mono<Branch[]> in order to create ResponseRepo

That was my recruitment task, so maybe it will help someone.

Comment: I believe that the way to get a `T` from a `Mono<T>` is to call one of the `block` methods.  That is what the [javadocs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) say.  Does that answer your question?  Obviously, that can't be done in a non-blocking way.

Comment: Filtering in `Flux` and `Mono` works just like filtering in `Stream` and `Optional` respectively.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. @StephenC with map() it works just fine, but can I use flatMap as @amanin answered? It is asynchronous, so is it one of `block` methods? @RobSpoor I added `.filter(repo -> !repo.fork())` after `.bodyToFlux(Repo.class)` and it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code sample, it looks like you want to use your `Branch[]` object in the middle of a reactive pipeline, as you use it to return a `Flux<ResponseRepo>`. In that case, use `map` or `flatMap` on your `Mono<Branch[]>`.

You can modify your `getReposInfo` as follows:

```java
    public Flux<ResponseRepo> getReposInfo(String username) {
        return getRepos(username)
                .flatMap(repo -> {
                    String name = repo.name();
                        String ownerLogin = repo.owner().login();
                        Mono<Branch[]> branches = getBranches(username, repo.name());
                        return branches.map(branchesValue -> new ResponseRepo(name, ownerLogin, branchesValue));
                });
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it works with `map`. How would you do this with `flatMap`?

Comment: `flatMap` is usable only if the operation result is a `Mono` or a `Flux`. It is not appropriate for simple in-memory operations.